# kendoui: array in js Object

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

here is a structure:

```
[{
   key: value,
   key: value,
   key: [
      key:value,
      key:value
      ...
   ],
   ...
   key:value
}]
```

I'm trying to bind it as a kendo DataSource and display as a kendoGrid elemnt. There is no problems with 1st level key:value pairs, but I broke my brains trying to get right with content of array. Is it even possible and, if yes, what am I doing wrong? If not - what is the best way to bind that?

Comment: Table is a straightforward flat structure, while your data is hierarhical. First thing you should think about is "how this data will look in grid?". There is structured sample in kendo demos http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html But as for me, it looks silly. If you ok with this, just follow the sample. Otherwise you may want to 1) restructure your data; 2) join inner arrays; 3) bind ul/li from it; 4) select another UI type for your data.

Comment: I'm ready to follow any of listed solution even if there is a point to do that. What I'm trying to do is to display user data (user able to edit and save data); user data contain standard things like phone number, e-mail etc. and questionnaire with up to 30 questions which should be answered just yes/no. Could You give me advice what is the best way to do that? Data is stored in mongodb, so, by my opinion, this is a more logical way to organize the data for current user account. Am I wrong?

Comment: Now I see what do you want to achieve; I agree that grid is good way to show user list, but big complex "questionnaire" structure is out of order for it. I see few solutions: popup dialog with questions showed by button click [(sample)](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-popup.html), with small notifier in main table that "questions: 30, answered: 10"; custom editor [(minor sample)](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html), this is a huge work indeed but you can implement your own cell type; finally not-a-grid solution, but stack of div's instead, even more hard solution.

Comment: A little correction: it's not a user LIST, it's just one user details in one grid (with single line) and questionnaire in another one; both grids use the same DataSource. Questionnaire is mandatory in this case, it should be filled in; user can't make profile active until it's not. This model seems silly, but I have no idea how to make it well...

Comment: Wow. Can you just separate this data source to two? Then you can bind second one (questions) to simple grid with columns Question and Answer. What I am missing?

Comment: aaa...it is part of registration process...all mandatory fields should be filled in including questionnaire...i see no way how to enable field validation otherwise. By the way it seems nice to all data be updated by one request...now I feel I'm just making situation more complicated, then it really is...

Comment: I don't get validation part, but if you'll send all data with one request, you can compile it as you want before sending. So, as I can see it: you define two structures/datasources: main and questions, then bind to two tables. When user filled data up, you compile json from two sources and send it. Somewhere between this steps should be injected validation step (you probably will delegate this task to grid editors?)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is going wrong without some more context on what you're trying to do but just judging by the fact that it's a dataSource, try changing:

```
   key: [
      key:value,
      key:value
      ...
   ],
```

to:

```
key: [
    {key:value},
    {key:value},
    ...
],
```

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. There already is key: [
    {key:value},
    {key:value},
    ...
], my problem is, that I want to display ONE Object, that contain a set of simple key:value pairs and one array of Objects.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand how you want that to appear in a grid view, but if you want the array to be nested within an existing element you might look at the Hierarchies example:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html

If you want the list to be within one cell, you'll probably have to manage the data to produce a single string that represents the array and use that. Sorry I can't be more help.